Why are my sliding door and my stucco disintegrating?
I have two strange problems going on right next to eachother.

I have an old alumnium sliding door that seems to be corroding away.
The stucco near the door is just kind of disintegrating.  There's now a bunch of "bubbles" of paint holding together powdered stucco with voids beneath.  If I tap on them, powder falls out.

This has been going on since we moved in in 2021.  I'm located in San Diego.  The wall faces north west.  The stucco on the rest of the wall (it's maybe 15 feet long) is fine.  There's no obvious moisture or moisture sources (no pipes in the wall or attic and the sprinklers don't hit the house -- although they might have before we arrived).  There's no signs of damage on the interior wall.
Any ideas what's going on?  Are the door and the stucco related?





Salt water/mist?

No, we are far from the ocean.

Is this stucco or Dryvit {polystyrene foam panels glued to the existing wall with a stucco finish)? Water is getting in behind the stucco. The stucco is delaminating from the existing wall. You have water stains on the sliding door threshold. The water is leaching out the alkalis from the stucco and eating the aluminum frame where it meets the stucco. I do not know where the water is coming from.

It's stucco.  That all make sense.  I can easily imagine that the sprinklers were hitting the house given the prior owner (was very elderly).  Does it make sense that stucco continues to degrade?

Remove the loose stucco and then refinish.
In the process, apply steel j-trim to the perimeter of the patio door opening so there is no contact between the stucco mortar and the aluminum frame to avoid further deterioration. Caulk the joint between the j-trim and the aluminum frame.
